# Saving a button image's state swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift2, nsuserdefaults, state

When a user presses a button the image changes to on. When the user leaves the View Controller I need it to remember that the button was set to image on the next time they go to this VC. I tried NSUser defaults to no avail. Can anybody help?

In the button action:

```
  buttonPressed = !buttonPressed

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    if buttonPressed == true {

        let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

        isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = true

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_on@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        print("follow")

        let following = PFObject(className: "Followers")
        following["following"] = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String
        following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        favLabel.text = "Favourite Jammer"

        following.saveInBackground()
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "SwitchState")

    } else {

        if buttonPressed != true {
            let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

            isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = false
            print("notFollow")
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_off@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            favLabel.text = "Add to favourites?"

            defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "SwitchState")
```

In the view did load:

```
  // save switch state:
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if (defaults.objectForKey("SwitchState") != nil) {
        buttonPressed = defaults.boolForKey("SwitchState")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my solutions below. Everytime you click the button it will change the status on and off. And it will saved the status if ever you leave the view controller. Let me know if this will help you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var imgTest: UIImageView!

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var setImageStatus: String = "off" {
        willSet {
            if newValue == "on" {
                imgTest.image = UIImage(named: "imgOn.png")
            } else {
                imgTest.image = UIImage(named: "imgOff.png")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let imgStatus = defaults.stringForKey("imgStatus")
        {
            setImageStatus = imgStatus
        } else {
            setImageStatus = "off"
        }

    }

    @IBAction func btnSave(sender: UIButton) {

        let stat = setImageStatus == "on" ? "off" : "on"
        setImageStatus = stat
        defaults.setObject(stat, forKey: "imgStatus")

    }
}
```

Comment: when I try to open the VC that the code is on it crashes on the line    `setImageStatus = status` ???

Comment: Jamster was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb)

Comment: (Jamster is the name of the app)

Comment: it works fine on mine... can you show the whole error... everything.. I will trace problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97247/discussion-between-user2749248-and-grace).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store something like this in your `AppDelegate`

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

    var myButtonSwitchState: Bool = false


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        //your code...
    }    

    //the rest of your code...

}
```

Then, in your view controller, you can get your app delegate by casting `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` to `AppDelegate`

```
var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Then, you can simply get and set the value of the boolean in the app delegate

```
func getSwitchState() -> Bool{
    return appDelegate.myButtonSwitchState
}

func setSwitchState(value: Bool){
    appDelegate.myButtonSwitchState = value
}
```

If you would like to store this state for once the user has quit the app (removed it from running apps), you can use `NSUserDefaults` and simply use this instead

```
func getSwitchState() -> Bool{
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("buttonStatus")
}

func setSwitchState(value: Bool){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value, forKey: "buttonStatus")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your input but I got it working with the first answer.

Comment: @Grace alright, I'm happy you got it working, but you should replace the strings "on" and "off" with booleans true and false